# Jenkins configuration as a code migration

Tags: jenkins, jcasc

We have a jenkins instance with [stable](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins) repository helm charts. As stable charts are deprecated, we are trying to upgrade our jenkins with [jenkinsci/helm-chart](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts) repository.

How to migrate our existing configuration to JCasc through helm chart?

Answer (score 1):

To migrate your existing configuration to JCasc, you can go to "Manage Jenkins" then "Configuration as code", and click on "View configuration" to get your current configuration as code.
You can also go directly to  https://your-jenkins-instance-url.example/configuration-as-code/viewExport

Select and copy all the export (Ctrl+A then Ctrl+C, there is a script on that page selecting only the export for you), then paste this content in your chart values.yaml as explained in [the jcasc documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/jenkins#configuration-as-code).